# Exit termite from within bash

Tags: bash, arch-linux, termite

I want to be able to completely close termite from within a bash script. I have something like this:

```
while true; do
    read -n 1 -s result
    case $result in
        [c]* ) exit 0;;
    esac
done
```

And I want hitting `c` to close termite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute your command with `exec` command to replace your bash with your script and when your script interpret `exit` command it will close your terminal.

Run your command like: `exec ./myscript.sh`

**NOTE:** Your script must have execute permission.